# How to get a substring until a specific character with preg_match in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Assuming I have these variations:

1: `Today is a beautiful day (Monday)`

2: `Today is a beautiful day`

I want to get `Today is a beautiful day`.

I'm trying `preg_match('/(?=(^\w+.+))$|(?=(^\w+.+)\s\())/ui', $string, $matches)` without success.

Comment: So everything until a parenthesis is what you want?

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `preg_match_all` with `multiline` option, like this:

```
^[^(]+(?=$|\s)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ4qO5/2)

Here is a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMR2tXR29kUFlPcWM):

```
<?php
   $re = "/^[^(]+(?=$|\s)/ui";
   $str = "Today is a beautiful day (Monday)"; 
   preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
   print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                               
(                                                                                                                                                                   
    [0] => Array                                                                                                                                                    
        (                                                                                                                                                           
            [0] => Today is a beautiful day                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        )                                                                                                                                                           

)
```

*DISCLAIMER*: As per your feedback, I am changing the regex line from `$re = "/^[^(]+(?=$|\\s)/m";` to `$re = "/^[^(]+(?=$|\s)/ui";` since it works for you.

Comment: Please fix the first line of the second code block. Must be `\s` instead of `\\s`.

Comment: @idknow: I do no have to fix anything, as I am using `/` delimiters with double quotation marks around the regex. Please see my sample program.

Comment: Ok, I added the change and a disclaimer. Also note that there is no point in using `i` option as there are no letters in the pattern.